# How can I offset the scroll on an html anchor?

Tags: html, anchor

I took a 1 page parallax scrolling template but I added more pages so it's not just a 1 page site anymore.

I figured out how to jump to the html anchors on the home page when your on a separate page. But now I have an offset issue that I just can't figure out.

The page is https://zoopyo.com - just click pricing or features and you'll see that the title gets cut off. The scroll just needs to be about 90px up. Which is the size of the sticky header. If the sticky header wasn't there it would be fine. So I just need to figure out how to offset it by 90px from the anchor. If that is even possible?

Comment: 404. Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: What is a fiddle? Other than an instrument

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ alternately post code here that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: I'll check that out. The problem is live right now though, can be seen at https://zoopyo.com/

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to load the website but from what I understand, the navbar is covering some content on top.

my suggestion would be to make an empty/dummy div at the top of the page with the same height as your navbar, then set your  to the dummy div, while maintaining the label of the first real div.

something like this:

```
 <li><a href="#dummy">top</a></li>
```

where dummy is empty and set to the height of your navbar

see this jsfiddle I made, the "hello world" is not covered by the navbar

http://jsfiddle.net/49AtS/1/